# Chrome tabs getting closed when i click on any link

Tags: google-chrome, wireless-mouse

I have bought a new wireless mouse. When I click on any link on a website, that particular tab gets closed. Other than this, the mouse is working fine in all cases.
I am unable to understand why and how to solve this problem.

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you see this similar behavior in the icognito mode too? If not then try removing or disabling the extensions like "AdBlock". Some users have reported this issue on "AdBlock" support page too.